# gcc x86 / x86_64 ABI : Must ss be equal to ds/es/fs/gs?

Tags: gcc, x86, x86-64, abi

It seems that I heard all data-segments are the same in both x86 and x86_64 ABI. But `ss` register is also? I'm writing kernel, and I want to detect stack overflow. To do that, It is required that `ss` segment selector is not equal to the other segment register...

Comment: You might want to read up on stack canaries / stack protectors (e.g. google for _x86_64 stack protector_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having SS different from other segment registers, especially different from the implicitly
used ones (CS, DS) would not be very good idea.

Most (practically all) x86 ABIs prescribe a flat address model, i.e. within the address
space of a process, a 64-bit address refers to the same memory location, no matter which
instruction uses that address to access that memory location.

That means that the contents of RSP can be moved to a general purpose register (say, R9) and
the same address can be used to access the same memory locations with PUSH, POP (which implicitly use SS) and with MOV (which implicitly uses DS).

And vice versa.

Having different segment register bases would necessitate using more memory for the pointer types (to store both the segment and the offset) and would create possibility for aliasing (having several different bit sequences denoting the same memory location).

Consider this:

```
void foo(int *ptr) {
    *ptr = 0;
}

void bar() {
    int x;
    foo(&x);
}

int y;

void baz() {
    foo(&y);
    bar();
}
```

If SS was different from DS, then either (non-exhaustive list)

- the pointer types should contain segment register too, or
- the compiler should perform some address translation when taking the address of a
  local variable

both of which impose some (time or space) overhead.